# Activity с меню, как?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать примерно такое активити с таким меню, где можно взять простой исходник? То, что брал я, это очень сложно, но похоже. На Github выбор не богат, а мне нужно простой исходник без всяких сложностей.

Может наглею. Но хочется подучится делать именно такое.[image: пример меню]

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вот [этот урок](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/navigation_drawer_activity.php)

Comment: Ну, как-то сложно. Мне бы исходный код весь :(

Comment: Ну если это сложно - то вам за готовым кодом на [github](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample)

Comment: А почему там всё на kotlin.. мне надо на java 

Comment: Все ясно - тогда вот [код на Java](https://bit.ly/2QqHMsi)

Comment: Ой, а я в яндексе искал. Спасибо :)